# No logro pasar una variable $_SESSION de un archivo a otro

Tags: php, variables, session

Tengo este código en el que le asigno un valor a la variable $_SESSION['idioma'] mediante GET:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['idioma'] = $_GET['l'] ?? 'en';
header("Location: /");
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
?>
```

Pero intento recoger dicha variable en otro archivo, y me da NULL como resultado:

```
          session_start();
          if (isset($_SESSION['idioma'])) {
            $idioma = $_SESSION['idioma'];
          } else {
            $idioma = 'en';
          }
          $archivo = file_exists("idiomas/$idioma.ini") ? "idiomas/$idioma.ini" : "idiomas/es.ini";
          $palabras = parse_ini_file("$archivo");
```

Lo he intentado en local y me sale bien, pero no así en el site de producción. ¿Por qué?

Gracias.

Comment: En el webserver ejecuta una página con un `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` y verifica si en `session.save_path` la ruta existe y si hay los permisos adecuados, además de las otras directivas. Ese parece ser un problema bastante común: [Enlace1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+sesion+funciona+local), [Enlace2](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+session+localhost+but+hosting).

Answer (score 0):

Si no es lo que aeportugal te comenta. Yo lo probé y me funciona perfecto.

Ojo que ese `if` que estas ocupando te está generando problemas. No entiendo muy bien lo que quieres preguntar con ese IF.

Para que Inglés sea por defecto cuando en la url exista la variable **l** (ele) debe ser así.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['idioma'] = $_GET['l'] ?: 'Ingles';
    header("Location: /snippets/");
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
?>
```

Y en el otro archivo

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['idioma'])) {
        $idioma = $_SESSION['idioma'];
    }

    echo 'Idioma es: '.$idioma;
?>
```

Pero eso funciona con una url asi: **http://localhost/snippets/parser.php?l**

Lo que no entiendo es porque quieres una url con una variable sin valor?

Answer (score 0):

El código funciona. Era un problema de que la sesión en el .index.php no se estaba iniciando porque se estaba enviando otra cosa debido a un problema con los encabezados.

La solución fue añadir en el php.ini lo siguiente:

```
output_buffering = 1
```

Y así se solucionó. Muchas gracias.